# React: Get initialstate after state has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to retrieve the initial state *after* the state has changed? F.ex:

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { foo: 'bar' }
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.setState({ foo: 'foo' })
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    // get the initial state "bar" ?
  }
})
```

I couldn’t find anything in the docs. I could of course save the value in an external variable, but I was just curios if it was possible to treat the initialstate as a "config" object that could be re-used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the initial state isn't stored -- but you can call `this.getInitialState()` if you want to reexecute the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the initial state in a variable:

```
React.createClass({
    initialState: { foo: 'bar' },

    getInitialState   : function () {
        return this.initialState;
    },
    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.setState({ foo: 'foo' })
    },
    componentDidMount : function () {
        console.log(this.initialState.foo); // Logs 'bar'
    }
});
```